# Accidental, unplanned breakthroughs in physics

Tags: experimental-physics, history, big-list

There is possibly some idiom or saying like this, "If you try too hard for something, you will never get it. If you do not aim for something, it may fall on you accidentally, not as you originally planned."

**In physics, or generally in science, there are many moments where success and triumph come from the accidental, unplanned attempts.** Moreover, there are some cases that originally were attempts for one specific question or a goal, but solved another seemingly unrelated problem, or reach seemingly opposite goals. There are these kinds of moments leading to a breakthrough of physics or science.

For example,

1. **Yang-Mills theory:** The original paper has attempted to explain a theory of nucleons, such as neutron and proton interactions with isospin symmetry, but it turns out that Yang-Mills theory as a non-Abelian gauge theory is suitable to describe a more fundamental subject, the gauge fields coupled to quarks and leptons in the standard model (EM, and especially the weak interaction and the strong interaction.)
2. **$Z_2$ topological insulator in 2+1D:** the original paper of [quantum spin hall effect from Kane and Mele](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.95.226801) is about graphene. But it turns out that the phenomenon is not present in graphene (C Kane jokes on this accident himself), but the physics is profound and correct, and later realized in CdTe/HgTe/CdTe quantum wells with a 2D film HgTe sandwiched.

**[Question]: Can any of the readers here list more?** Both in theory or in experiments. Making an inspiring list for eager-minded scientists at Phys.SE here. To give us some inspiration and high motivations to be subconsciously aware of those random accidental moments.

Comment: I'm sure it used to be that list questions were explicitly banned, though I've had a quick look at the faq and I can't see anything to that effect. However I'd guess the question will be closed on the grounds of being too broad.

Comment: The relevant meta question is, I think, [Good list, bad list](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list).

Comment: Is listing CdTe twice in "CdTe/HgTe/CdTe" a typo?

Comment: Don't forget the discovery of [the heating effect of microwaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Accidental_discovery).

Comment: @Dan Neely. No, CdTe/HgTe/CdTe is not a typo. It is correct. CdTe/HgTe/CdTe is a sandwich decice with a HgTe in the middle.

Comment: To potential lions or wanderers: it is potentially an interesting question, everyone with certain background knowledge can brainstorm and contribute to the question. If having time judging the question, why not spending time instead on improving the list of examples...? I myself having many more inspiring examples. Thank you.

Comment: The very fact that *"everyone can brainstorm and contribute"* is exactly why this is not a good question for the site.

Comment: @dmckee do we not have [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4561/2751) now ...?!

Comment: There is also that string theory was first supposed to be a theory for scattering of hadrons but then some nasty gravitons popped up that could not have gotten rid off  ... ;-)

Comment: @dmckee and such questions do the site a better service in attracting new good experts because they are interesting than the lazy effortless low-level one-liners it gets flooded with and which are allowed to hang around and get answers of the same kind !

Comment: A few of the most important ones are still missing:
The magnetic effect of electric currents by Oersted (or better by Gian Domenico Romagnosi), radioactivity, quantum mechanics (Planck's constant playing a role in the photoelectric effect and in atomic physics) the laser, pulsars, holography, 
high-temperature superconductivity.

Nassim Taleb called these events in his same-named bestseller "black swans".

Comment: I will be happier to see this question to survive here, instead of being closed or removed. This question does the job to examine those important physics breakthroughs - how accidental the discoveries were made. It is totally a nontrivial creative question, because "accidental" and "breakthrough" together are nontrivial. You can have many accidents, and you can have some breakthroughs, but usually not together. I will bet that the list of these accidental important breakthroughs is finite many, possibly an order of 100, much less than 1000.

Comment: If we gain this list at Phys.SE, people can start from here to ask more details the essence of how these theories and experiments are performed, and how the viewpoints have been changed before/after breakthroughs (We have focused too much on canonical viewpoints in the past). Wouldn't that be wonderful?  It also lead a group of more amateur physics lover into understanding more about important physics topics and breakthroughs. It would be a sad story to see the Big Brothers like George Orwell's 1984 killing this question without a 2nd thought. Big Brothers are too powerful outweighing others.

Comment: DavidZ has opened a [meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/why-should-the-list-of-breakthroughs-in-physics-be-allowed) about this. @called2voyage

Answer (score 8):

A few more here:

**Fractional quantum hall effects**: had heard that the large magnetic field is originally aimed to see the Wigner crystal effect, instead of testing quantum hall physics.

**Asymptotic freedom** (QCD running couplings to small at high energy): from Wilczek's book ``Longing for the Harmonies,'' at that time David Gross originally aimed to prove that QFT cannot explain the Bjorken scaling, i.e. prove that (non-Abelian) QFT always lead to large coupling at high energy, simply that QFT cannot explain the couplings run to small at high energy. But the final result is the opposite. And they won the Nobel Prize.

**String theory**: originally aimed for explaining strong interaction, but not as successful as QCD. String had then been abandoned for a long while. Later string theory turned out to be a candidate for a theory of everything.

**Inflation(cosmology)**: Alan Guth firstly studied particle physics and magnetic monopole in grand unified theory(GUT). He encountered the magnetic monopole problem (the sparsity of magnetic monopoles in the universe). Initially there is no significant progress. But he and colleagues turned out to detour to use a theory of supercooling to understand the phase transition of the early universe, which produces a false vacuum then decay to produces Inflation. This new idea discovery of Inflation goes backward solving the magnetic monopole problem.

**The non-existence of luminiferous ether**: Michelson and Morley  had initially hypothesised that luminiferous ether exists, but they ended up showing otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

**The Stern-Gerlach Experiment**: originally setting out to corroborate the Bohr-Sommerfield hypothesis that the direction of the angular momentum of an atom is quantized, it was eventually realized that the proper interpretation of the observations was as the first evidence of particle spin and that the electron is a spin-1/2 particle.

**The Spin-Statistics Theorem**: I can't imagine anyone expected this jewel to pop out of the union of quantum mechanics with special relativity.

Comment: actually Spin-Statistics Theorem may not need to have special relativity. What you implied may be is the CPT theorem derived in QFT. For Spin-Statistics, Quantum mechanics alone is good enough to derive. ps. In 2+1D, using fermions as the string ends, doing the trick of Feynman's plate also can show Spin-Statistics Theorem. Levin-Wen String-net also does the job to show Spin-Statistics Theorem. **It will also be better to say what this is accidental and unplanned from a historical viewpoint.**

Answer (score 5):

**Discovery of X-rays**: it happened when Röngten discovered that some photographic plates received radiation even if they were unexposed.

Comment: Pls check this: I'm pretty sure you're confusing Röntgen with Becquerel

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Becquerel discovered radioactivity, Röngten X-rays

Comment: Agreed, but I seem to recall the photographic plates were Bequerel's detector, whereas Röntgen I think used something different.